# Regarding the slicing of an Nd array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When learning numpy, I conducted the following experiment:

```
 x = np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5,2))

 x
Out[5]: 
array([[[0, 5],
    [8, 2],
    [8, 3],
    [6, 5],
    [4, 5]],
   [[9, 8],
    [2, 1],
    [7, 7],
    [0, 3],
    [3, 0]],
   [[4, 8],
    [4, 3],
    [1, 8],
    [7, 3],
    [6, 0]],
   [[3, 0],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 6],
    [0, 6],
    [9, 7]],
   [[1, 8],
    [0, 8],
    [0, 2],
    [9, 3],
    [7, 1]]])
```

Then, I tried `x1 = x[:,1:-1]`. It will generate a`(5,3,2)` array. I don't understand why the `1:-1` in `x[:,1:-1]` will turn out to affect the second dimension of x, instead of the third dimension. In other words, given something like `x1=x[:,1:-1]`, how can I know the shape of resulting x1, what's the rule underlying it.

If I type `x1=x[1:-1,:]`, then x will be of shape `(3,3,2)`. I just feel confused about how does this slicing rule work.

Comment: `x[1:-1, :]` will have shape `(3, 5, 2)`, not `(3, 3, 2)`. That's because you're selecting indices from `1` (so excluding `0`), upto and not including the last, i.e. `-1`, in the first dimension. The second dimension remains unaffected because you just said `:`. You can achieve the same effect with just `x[1:-1]`, and not specifying the second and the third dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `x1 = x[:,1:-1]`. It will generate a `(5,3,2)` array.

Why doesn't it affect the third dimension, it's because you supplied arguments only for the first two dimensions. The comma separates the dimensions. As the third argument is not given, all elements of the third dimension are considered by default. It is no different from `x1 = x[:,1:-1,:]`.

> If I type `x1=x[1:-1,:]`, then x will be of shape (3,3,2).

Yes, it should be. You will find that `x1=x[1:-1,:,:]` and `x1=x[1:-1]` will yeild the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the 1:-1 in x[:,1:-1] will turn out to affect the second dimension of x, instead of the third dimension

It affects the second dimension because the `:` that is before the comma affects the first dimension. In other words, if you simply did `x1 = x[1:-1]` instead, you'd get a `(3, 5, 2)` array. For each comma, you affect one dimension after, starting from the *first* one.